# Argument of a Cosine function (referring to Principles of QM by R. Shankar)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, waves

On Page 72, Shankar solves the differential equation:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}\langle m\rvert\psi(t)\rangle=-\left(\frac{m^2\pi^2}{L^2}\right)\langle m\rvert\psi(t)\rangle$$
as:
$$ \langle m\rvert\psi(t)\rangle=\langle m\rvert\psi(0)\rangle\cos{\frac{m\pi t}{L}}$$
where $m$ was previously shown to be dimensionless (not explicitly though). This seems alright, however $L$ was previously shown to denote length and therefore has a physical dimension, and so does $t$.

Isn't the argument of a trigonometric function supposed to be dimensionless? Why isn't it so over here?

Comment: The units in the PDE you're trying to solve, $\ddot\psi=\psi''$, are already messed up. This is just a manifestation of this fact.

Comment: @0celo7 : A $v^2$ (velocity) term on the right should fix it right?

Comment: Yes, that fixes it.